# Android : sqlite join result

Tags: android, sqlite, join

I have a table which has one column's `name` and `guestof` .

I want to return a cursor to get three values : `name` `guestOf` and `guestcount` where `guestcount` is how many rows has "name" as the value of `guestOf`.

How can combine this internal query and return the result. Trying something like this, can it be done without inner query for better performance

```
SELECT name, guestCount from Table
   as A outer join (SELECT guestOf , count(*) 
   AS GuestCount FROM Table group by guestOf) 
   as GuestCounts WHERE  A.id = GuestCounts.guestOf
```

Comment: can you add to your question the code for what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Give this code a go. I think it matches what you're looking for:

```
SELECT g.name, g.guestof, 
    (SELECT COUNT(guestof) 
         FROM guests AS c
         WHERE g.name == c.guestof
     ) as guestcount
FROM guests AS g;
```

And as an example: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/687b8/1)

Comment: @preetha - Has this answer helped you at all? If so, please be sure to accept it by clicking the ✔ on the left.